# Django Unit Testing for standalone variables (coverage)

Tags: django, unit-testing, coverage.py

I'm starting to write unit tests for a django project, and running coverage shows I have 0% coverage over a simple list of tuples.

Example:

```
STATE_CHOICES = [
    ("MO", "Missouri",),
    ("AL", "Alabama",),
]
```

Is there some kind of test I could write to get coverage over this list of tuples?
I assumed simple

`len() > 0` and `is not None`

tests would cover it, but apparently not.

Comment: Well, you could check if STATE_CHOICES equals to what you expect it should be, but I don't know if Coverage would be pleased with something like that

Comment: I'd end up copy-pasting it into the test, there are a lot of choices

Comment: What do you mean by "0% coverage over a simple list of tuples"?  Coverage.py doesn't try to measure data coverage.

Comment: a file with a list of tuples shows in my coverage report at 0% coverage and I'd prefer not to omit the file